# Java lottery repeat program

Tags: java, loops

I need this lottery program to repeat itself a certain number of times and then stop, but I am having trouble on where to place the for loop (if that's what I should use). How can I display the percentage of times 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 numbers matched out of all the runs?

```
    package assignment5;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    import java.util.Random;
    public class assignment5
    {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    lottery pic=new lottery();
    pic.Get_player_numbers();
    pic.Get_jackpot_number();
    pic.Check_winner ();
    pic.Write_data();

}
    }
    class lottery
    {

int[] picks= new int[5];
int[] cpick=new int[5];
int i;
int j,c;
int match=0;

void Get_player_numbers ()

{
    int ctemp,cdupflag=0;
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        //YOU DO NOT NEED THE CNUMBERFLAG
        //IF YOU GENERATED THE NUMBERS CORRECLTY, THE COMPUTER WILL NOT GENERATE ONE ABOVE 99 OR LESS THAN 1
       cdupflag=0;
        while(cdupflag==0)
         {
            ctemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
            cdupflag=1;
            for(c=0;c<=j;++c)
               {
                 if(ctemp==cpick[c])
                    {
                     cdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
            if(cdupflag==1) 
                   cpick[j]=ctemp;
          }
    }
    String Jackpot="User Lottery numbers are: "+"\n";
    //String computer = "";
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        if(j==4)
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j];   
        else
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j]+"-";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Jackpot,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

//void jackpot()
void Get_jackpot_number()
{

    int ctemp,cdupflag=0;
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        //YOU DO NOT NEED THE CNUMBERFLAG
        //IF YOU GENERATED THE NUMBERS CORRECLTY, THE COMPUTER WILL NOT GENERATE ONE ABOVE 99 OR LESS THAN 1
       cdupflag=0;
        while(cdupflag==0)
         {
            ctemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
            cdupflag=1;
            for(c=0;c<=j;++c)
               {
                 if(ctemp==cpick[c])
                    {
                     cdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
            if(cdupflag==1) 
                   cpick[j]=ctemp;
          }
    }
    String Jackpot="Computer Lottery numbers are: "+"\n";
    //String computer = "";
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        if(j==4)
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j];   
        else
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j]+"-";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Jackpot,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}


void Check_winner ()
{

    for(int i=0;i<=4;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=4;++j)
        {
            if(picks[i]==cpick[j])
            {
                match=match+1;
            }
        }
    }

}


void Write_data ()
{
    String print = "";

    if(match==0)
    {
        print=print+"There is no match"+"\n";
        print=print+"please try again "+"\n";
    }
    else
    if(match==1)
    {
        print=print+"There is one match"+"\n";
        print=print+"You won 100 Dollars "+"\n";
    }
    else 
        if(match==2)
        {
            print=print+"There are two matches"+"\n";
            print=print+"You won 1,000 Dollars"+"\n";
        }
        else
            if(match==3)
            {
                print=print+"There are three matches"+"\n";
                print=print+"You won 10,000 Dollars "+"\n";
            }
            else
                if(match==4)
                {
                    print=print+"There are four matches"+"\n";
                    print=print+"You won 100,000 Dollars "+"\n";
                }
                else
                    if(match==5)
                    {
                        print=print+"There are five matches"+"\n";
                        print=print+"You won 1,000,000 Dollars"+"\n";
                    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,print,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}}

    //end of class lottery
```

Comment: You should capitalize class names, start methods with a lowercase letter and use camelCasing to separate words in identifiers (an identifier is a variable/class/method name). You also shouldn't use cryptic identifiers like `c` and `j`. Instead, use names to specify what those variables actually represent. ***On-Topic***: Do you want to start a new lottery game each time? What have you tried?

Comment: I want a different game each time but i need to be able to track the jackpot and winning numbers through out all of the runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the loop: It should go in main around the things you're doing for lottery

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < [NumberOfRepeats]; i++)
    {
        lottery pic=new lottery();
        pic.Get_player_numbers();
        pic.Get_jackpot_number();
        pic.Check_winner ();
        pic.Write_data();
    }
}
```

As for counting the percentages  you'll need to modify the code for 'write_data()' to store or return the number of matches (probably in an array), then divide by the total number of runs for each.

Comment: Thank you very much, I kept trying to put it lower and it was messing everything up. I should be able to figure out how to store all the runs.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To figure out how much those numbers have come up in relation to the rest, keep counters for each number and one for the total amount then just do some simple division.

Answer (score 0):

```
package loop;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class loop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Lottery pic=new Lottery();
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            pic.getPlayerNumbers();
            pic.getJackpotNumbers();
            pic.checkWinner();
            pic.assignPayout();
            pic.stringBuilderOne();
        }
        pic.stringBuilderTwo();
        pic.writeData();
    }
}//end loop

class Lottery
{
    private final int[] ppick= new int[5];
    private final int[] cpick=new int[5];
    private int match=0;
    private int i;
    private double matchcount0=0;
    private double matchcount1=0;
    private double matchcount2=0;
    private double matchcount3=0;
    private double matchcount4=0;
    private double matchcount5=0;
    private int jackpot = 25000000;
    private int payout;
    private final StringBuilder builderOne = new StringBuilder();
    private final StringBuilder builderTwo = new StringBuilder();

    void getPlayerNumbers ()
    {
        int ptemp,pdupflag;
        for(i =0; i <=4;++i)
        {
            pdupflag=0;
            while(pdupflag==0)
            {
                ptemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
                pdupflag=1;
                int p;
                for(p =0; p<= i;++p)
                {
                    if(ptemp==ppick[p])
                    {
                        pdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
                if(pdupflag==1)
                    ppick[i]=ptemp;
            }
        }
    }//end getPlayerNumbers

    void getJackpotNumbers()
    {
        int ctemp,cdupflag;
        int j;
        for(j =0; j <=4;++j)
        {
            cdupflag=0;
            while(cdupflag==0)
            {
                ctemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
                cdupflag=1;
                int c;
                for(c =0; c <= j;++c)
                {
                    if(ctemp==cpick[c])
                    {
                        cdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
                if(cdupflag==1)
                    cpick[j]=ctemp;
            }
        }
        String Jackpot="Computer Lottery numbers are: "+"\n";
        //String computer = "";
        for(j =0; j <=4;++j)
        {
            if(j ==4)
                Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j];
            else
                Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j]+"-";
        }
    }//end getJackpot numbers

    void checkWinner ()
    {
        match=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=4;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=4;++j)
            {
                if(ppick[i]==cpick[j])
                {
                    match=match+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }//end checkWinner

    void assignPayout () {
        if (match == 0) {
            matchcount0 = matchcount0 + 1;
            payout = 0;
            jackpot = jackpot + 25000;
        } else if (match == 1) {
            matchcount1 = matchcount1 + 1;
            payout = 100;
            jackpot = jackpot + 100000;
        } else if (match == 2) {
            matchcount2 = matchcount2 + 1;
            jackpot = jackpot + 250000;
            payout = 1000;
        } else if (match == 3) {
            matchcount3 = matchcount3 + 1;
            jackpot = jackpot + 500000;
            payout = 10000;
        } else if (match == 4) {
            matchcount4 = matchcount4 + 1;
            jackpot = jackpot + 1000000;
            payout = 100000;
        } else if (match == 5) {
            matchcount5 = matchcount5 + 1;
            payout = jackpot;
            jackpot = 2500000;
        }
    }//end assignPayout

    void stringBuilderOne ()
    {
            builderOne.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
                    .append("Current Jackpot     Player#         Winner#          #Matched      Payout\n")
                    .append(jackpot).append("         ")
                    .append(ppick[0]).append(" ")
                    .append(ppick[1]).append(" ")
                    .append(ppick[2]).append(" ")
                    .append(ppick[3]).append(" ")
                    .append(ppick[4]).append("    ")
                    .append(cpick[0]).append(" ")
                    .append(cpick[1]).append(" ")
                    .append(cpick[2]).append(" ")
                    .append(cpick[3]).append(" ")
                    .append(cpick[4]).append("        ")
                    .append(match).append("            ")
                    .append(payout);
    }//end stringBuilderOne

    void stringBuilderTwo ()
    {
        builderTwo.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
                .append("\nThe percent of plays where 0 numbers matched = ")
                .append(matchcount0 / i * 100).append("%\nThe percent of plays where 1 numbers matched = ")
                .append(matchcount1 / 10).append("%\nThe percent of plays where 2 numbers matched = ")
                .append(matchcount2 / 10).append("%\nThe percent of plays where 3 numbers matched = ")
                .append(matchcount3 / 10).append("%\nThe percent of plays where 4 numbers matched = ")
                .append(matchcount4 / 10).append("%\nThe percent of plays where 5 numbers matched = ")
                .append(matchcount5 / 10).append("%\n");
    }//End stringBuilderTwo

    void writeData ()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedWriter lotteryOutput = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.dat"));
                lotteryOutput.write(builderOne.toString());
                lotteryOutput.write(builderTwo.toString());
            lotteryOutput.close();
        }//end try
        catch (IOException error)
            {
            //there was an error on the write to the file
            System.out.println("Error on file write " + error);
        }//end error
    }//end writeData
}//end of class lottery
```

This accomplishes all of the requirements you have mentioned.